# ¿Cómo hacer un update a una columna cumpliendo dos condiciones con DISTINCT en una condición?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Mi consulta (intento) es la siguiente:

```
UPDATE clientes_dinersTC
SET CET = 1 
FROM 
(
  select distinct([VENDOR LEAD CODE])
  from clientes_dinersTC
  where Mejor_Estado_Cliente IN ('CONTACTO EFECTIVO CON TITULAR',
                                 'CONTACTO EFECTIVO')
);
```

Quiero hacer un update a una columna llamada CET=1  y, para esto necesito que cumpla algunas condiciones siguientes:

1. Que la columna “mejor_estado_cliente” solo tenga los valores (‘CONTACTO EFECTIVO CON TITULAR’ y ‘CONTACTO EFECTIVO’).
2. Una vez cumplido la primera condición. Hacer que los valores de la columna “VENDOR LEAD CODE” (son números de identificación repetidos) seas únicos y no repetidos.
3. Por último, una vez que se han cumplido las condiciones 1 y 2, poner un 1 en cada fila de la columna “CET” que cumpla las condiciones anteriores. Muchas gracias

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. MySQL o SQL Server? Las etiquetas nos dicen qué tener en cuenta, úsalas sabiamente. Cuál es el problema con la consulta de acuerdo a lo que necesitas? Qué sale y qué debe salir? Con qué datos de prueba podrían otros replicar el problema o saber si la salida es la que esperas? Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).

Comment: Todavía tienes etiquetas contradictorias. MySQL es un DBMS, SQL Server es otro. ¿Cuál de los dos usas? Remueve la etiqueta incorrecta. Y por favor lee lo que ha escrito Alfabravo. Entiende lo que falta en tu pregunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. De tu tabla quieres sacar todas las filas que tienen el valor 'CONTACTO EFECTIVO CON TITULAR' o el valor 'CONTACTO EFECTIVO'.
2. De este resultado quieres sacar las filas que tienen un "VENDOR LEAD CODE" único en este resultado.
3. Y estas filas quieres actualizar con `UPDATE ... SET CET = 1`.

En otras palabras: Quieres actualizar todas filas que tienen el valor 'CONTACTO EFECTIVO CON TITULAR' o el valor 'CONTACTO EFECTIVO' y para los quienes no hay otra fila con el valor 'CONTACTO EFECTIVO CON TITULAR' y el mismo "VENDOR LEAD CODE".

```
UPDATE clientes_dinerstc
SET cet = 1
WHERE mejor_estado_cliente IN ('CONTACTO EFECTIVO CON TITULAR', 'CONTACTO EFECTIVO')
AND NOT EXISTS
(
  SELECT NULL
  FROM clientes_dinerstc otra
  WHERE otra.id <> clientes_dinerstc.id
  AND otra.mejor_estado_cliente IN ('CONTACTO EFECTIVO CON TITULAR', 'CONTACTO EFECTIVO')
  AND otra.[VENDOR LEAD CODE] = clientes_dinerstc.[VENDOR LEAD CODE]
);
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=843fb5178b4797bdad266d1a46c8fc64

O con `COUNT OVER` para encontrar los distintos [VENDOR LEAD CODE] en el resultado intermedio, que es más como la primera explicación de la tarea (tres pasos):

```
UPDATE cd
SET cet = 1
FROM
(
  SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY [VENDOR LEAD CODE]) AS cnt
  FROM clientes_dinerstc
  WHERE mejor_estado_cliente IN ('CONTACTO EFECTIVO CON TITULAR', 'CONTACTO EFECTIVO')
) cd
WHERE cnt = 1;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=392cbd3ce86dff440d31e6e5c966a21a

Comment: Muchas gracias, estimado. Me ha funcionado el segundo script.

Comment: Hola, que tal. cómo podría insertar la clausula "Disctinct" dentro del "Over partition by" para poder asignar a la columna "CET" = 1 . 

Esto es a lo que me refiero:
BEGIN TRAN
UPDATE cd
SET cet = 1
FROM
(
SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY (DISTINCT [VENDOR LEAD CODE])) AS cnt
from clientes_dinersTC 
where Mejor_Estado_Cliente IN ('CONTACTO EFECTIVO CON TITULAR','CONTACTO EFECTIVO')
) cd
WHERE cnt = 1;
{
SELECT DISTINCT([VENDOR LEAD CODE]) 
FROM clientes_dinersTC
WHERE  Mejor_Estado_Cliente IN ('CONTACTO EFECTIVO CON TITULAR','CONTACTO EFECTIVO')
} esta es mi respuesta.

Comment: No entiendo que estas preguntando. `COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY [VENDOR LEAD CODE])` te da la información cuantas veces el `VENDOR LEAD CODE` esta en los resultados. Si es distinto = único = ocurre una sola vez, el cnt es 1, y entonces haces el UPDATE. ¿Que otra cosa quieres que sea distinto/unico?

Comment: Quisiera colocar este código “SELECT DISTINCT([VENDOR LEAD CODE]) 
FROM clientes_dinersTC
WHERE  Mejor_Estado_Cliente IN ('CONTACTO EFECTIVO CON TITULAR','CONTACTO EFECTIVO')” dentro de la subconsulta junto con el “count” y “over” para poder tener “1”, ya que, cuando solo uso count(*) over (partition by [VENDOR LEAD CODE]), solo cuenta los números únicos y eso no quiero. Espero me deje explicar.

Comment: No entiendo. Pero en este punto debe ser posible que resuelvas el problema tu mismo. Ya entiendes cómo funcionan mis dos consultas. Entiendes que hacen la misma cosa y por qué tienen el mismo resultado. Entiendes cada paso, pero no sabes cómo alterar la primera o la segunda consulta para obtener el resultado que quieres. Entonces toma un papel. dibuja una tabla con datas de tu tabla. Decide el primer paso para tener un base para los pasos que quedan. En mis consultas el primer paso es `WHERE mejor_estado_cliente IN (...)`. Dibuja la tabla del resultado. Decide el segundo paso. Dibuja, Etc.